# Is it not possible to call/declare a function in an static function?

Tags: php

That's my Class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static function test($data)
    {

       function clean($item, $key)
       {         ...do something
           }

           array_walk_recursive($data, 'clean');
 ...
```

I'am calling the class by:

```
MyClass::test("$data")
```

The error-message I get:

> Error: [2] array_walk_recursive() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'clean' not found or invalid function name

Comment: 1. This does not work as you think it does and you shouldn't do this. 2. Are you in a namespace perchance?

Comment: Just move the declaration out of the static function, it will still be visible.

Comment: @SPlatten It doesn't make any difference in this case whether you declare the function inside or outside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign your function to a variable, and then reference that in the call to `array_walk_recursive`:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static function test($data)
    {
        $clean = function ($item, $key) {
           // do something
        };

       array_walk_recursive($data, $clean);
    }
}

$data = [1, 2, [3, 4, 5]];
MyClass::test($data);
```

Alternatively, just pass the callback directly, if you don't need to re-use it elsewhere:

```
array_walk_recursive($data, function ($item, $key) {
    // ...
});
```

What you've currently got will work correctly, but your `clean` function won't be limited to the local scope. PHP allows you to define functions at any level, but they will be created in global scope (or in the scope of any namespace you're currently using).

After the first call to `MyClass::test`, your code will allow calls to `clean` outside of the context of your static class, which may not be desirable.

Comment: You don't ***"need"*** to, but this is certainly better than what OP does.

Comment: OK. I pass the callback directly. But how to declare a function in the current scope only?

Comment: How to call the function clean outsite the scope? I tried clean, $clean. Both do not work. Call to undefined function...

Comment: PHP doesn't support declaring functions in "local" scope. Whenever you write `function xxx() { ... }`, you're declaring a function in either global scope, or in the scope of whichever namespace you're operating in. Your original code didn't mention a namespace, but if your class is within `namespace Foo`, then you can call your the function as `Foo\clean($item, $key);`

Comment: @iainn thx it works perfect. but i do not have any clue why i have to assign the function to a variable? thx for any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

In class as you have static method you can call function with 'self'

```
class MyClass_test
{
    public static function test_this($data)
    {
       array_walk_recursive($data,array("self","clean"));
     }
     public static function clean($item, $key)
     {        //Do something
     }

}
$data = array(1,2,3);
MyClass_test::test_this();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?

class MyClass { 

    static function clean($item, $key) {
            echo $item.PHP_EOL;
    }

    public static function test($data)
    {        
        array_walk_recursive( $data, 'MyClass::clean'); 
    }
}

$a = [1,2,3];

MyClass::test($a);

?>

php select.php 
1
2
3
```

It's a solution that you need. If you don't want to use callbacks.